# Print number from a line

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am new to programming and can't seem to wrap my head around this question. Any help is appreciated and I have my code currently shown. Thank you so much in advanced.

First line of input contains the number of lines to follow

- First number of each line, `n >= 2`, contains the number of integers that follow in the line
- Those n integers (each integer `>= 0; <= 1000`) follow till the end of the line, and should be stored (except the last one) in an array using index numbers `1...n - 1`
- The last integer p (`p >= 1 & p <= n - 1`) in the line is the index (starting from 1) of the integer to select from the line and print

Code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Scanner to take the inputs
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Variables
    int numOfLines;
    int di = 0;
    int n;

    // The arrays to store the results
    int[] data = new int[100];
    int[] result = new int[100];

    System.out.println("**Input**");
    // Read number of lines to follow
    numOfLines = input.nextInt();
    while (di < numOfLines) {
        // Read first integer of each line
        n = input.nextInt();
        // Store n-1 integers to array
        for (int dj = 1; dj <= n - 1; dj++) {
            data[dj] = input.nextInt();
        }
        // Multiply selected numbers and store to array
        result[di] = data[dj];
        di++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

You say that you can't wrap your head around the question. The first thing to do is to clearly understand the problem before coding anything. To make it clearer, on each line, the user will enter something like this:

```
4 500 600 700 1
```

- The first number tells how many numbers come after it. You see here that there are four that follow it.
- The last number tells which index to print. You see that the first number is wanted.
- The numbers in the middle are the numbers which can be chosen.

So, the output should be the first number in the middle, which is 500, so the output should be something like:

```
The number is: 500
```

---

According to your specifications, you have some problems in your code:

1. The `data` array can't have a fixed size (like 100) in your source code, since, if you choose a fixed size for it, the user can always choose a line with more numbers in it than the `data` array can hold. You should replace `data` with a new properly-sized array at the beginning of each line of input.
2. There's no need for the `result` array, since you merely need to print out the desired number right away without needing to store it for later.
3. `// Multiply selected numbers and store to array` is an incorrect comment which should be removed.
4. You need to add a line of code to input the last number entered on the line as the desired index.
5. You need to print out the number at that desired index in `data`.

---

I'd recommend, for learning's sake:

1. Taking the time to understand the problem
2. Getting a clear understanding of why these changes are necessary
3. Making the changes
4. Checking that things work properly
5. Practice by starting from scratch (in a new source code file so you don't delete your working version) with your better understanding and seeing if you can get it working without help